# Should a transcript appear in both the media and the citation?

Tags: citation, transcriptions

Take this **media** entry:

[image: Extract from a book]

As you can see, I added it as a **transcript**.

And take this **citation**:

[image: Citation of entry]

I have added the transcript in both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source should show the document you consulted in the form (original or image or PDF) available to you. If the media was only available as a transcript, or index, or offline original, your citation should say so.

However you consulted the source, you should include your transcript (as this is the record of what you **think** the source said. Others might think differently, if the media is hard to read, for example; or they might not be able to consult the source you used; or the source might become unavailable online if the agreement between the person (etc.) who hold the rights to publish and the current publisher (currently, Ancestry) expires, and you can no longer view the media.  (it has happened more often than you might care to think).

Comment: You can see in my case the quality of the document. :) So where is the transcript of the pertinent part kept - with the citation or with the media or both?

Comment: I keep it with the source which is linked both to the citation and the media. If I used Ancestry (which I don't, or only as a copy from my tree), I'd keep it wherever it would survive if Ancestry withdrew access to the source/media.